# solving the following equation:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find all integer solutions of the equation $9x+5y=77$. This equation obviously has a whole family of solutions which I was also able to see on Wolfram Alpha but I dont know to get to that solution. Can anyone explain how to get there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: yes im familiar with it, that's also something I played around with a little to find a way to solve it but it didn't quite work

Comment: Try it mod $5$ or mod $9$.  What do you get?

Comment: then we have $(77-9x)mod5=0$, I dont know where to go from this point

Comment: Can you spot a particular solution $x_0, y_0$? Then $9(x-x_0)+5(y-y_0)=0$. Since 9 and 5 have no factor in common what can you now say about $x-x_0$ and $y-y_0$?

Comment: It is a linear Diophantine equation. [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) has a section on its solutions.

Comment: $\bmod 5\,$ it reduces to $\, -x \equiv 2 \iff x\equiv -2 \equiv 3\iff \color{#c00}{x = 3\!+\!5n}\,$ therefore $\,y = (77-9\color{#c00}x)/5 = (77-9(\color{#c00}{3\!+\!5n}))/5 = 10-9n.\,$ See the linked dupes for these standard methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the equation mod $5$, you get
$$ 4 x \equiv 2 \mod 5$$
so
$$ x \equiv 2 \cdot 4^{-1} \equiv 3 \mod 5 $$
Similarly, taking the equation mod $9$, you get
$$ y \equiv 5 \cdot 5^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod 9 $$
Now with $x = 3 + 5 s$ and $y = 1 + 9 t$ your equation becomes
$$ 32 + 45s + 45t = 77$$
or
$$ 45 s + 45 t = 45 $$
Thus $s+t = 1$: the solution can be written as
$$ x = 3 + 5 s,\ y = 1 + 9 (1-s) = 10 - 9 s$$
where $s$ is an integer.

Comment: Thank you Robert! This makes sense to me, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).